# Change the value of a column based on the value of another column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To clarify I'll give an example:

- Dataframe has 2 columns: Currency and Price
- Currency has 3 unique values: EUR, GBP, USD
- I need to set the prices, as they are all in USD
- I need to multiply those values that are GBP and EUR with another double, i.e. 1.15 and 1.5 respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
df['value'][df['Currency'] == 'GBP'] = df['value'][df['Currency'] == 'GBP'] * GBP_factor
```

Comment: The solution fits perfectly! Appreciate it!